# Azurelocated Odata tables through SHIR to azure sql db using ADF/Visualstudio

Tags: oauth-2.0, odata, oracle-adf

I can't get Odata tables from service (located in azure) with SSO sign on through the selfhosted integration runtime using ADF or MS visual studio --> to azure sql db table

ADF odataconnector (windows authentication)
ADF Rest (OAuth2 client credential)
ADF Http (windows authentication)

I have done succesfully the pipeline in adf which gives me a token in output for OAuth2 using this link to watch some example (https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/azure-data-factory-retrieve-token-from-azure-ad-using-oauth-2-0-9a3ed3f55013) but i still can't get a working copy data activity that i could get any kind of data out of the service to azure sql database.

Have tried (odataconnector, rest, http) as a source but there is problems when trying to make succesful connection that could get even one table out

and still I can connect via browser to the service using SSO connection :)
and I have owner rights in azurelocated service.